# Redirect to different page on buttonclick in a lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a site where a button opens a lightbox with another button.
The button inside the lightbox has an href value of a download url.
My task is to redirect to a different page after that button is clicked.
I've tried using:

```
window.location = nextsite.com
window.location.href = nextsite.com
window.location.replace(nextsite.com)
window.location.assign(nextsite.com)
```

It works if I put the lightboxCTA id on the button that brings up the lightbox.
However, if it's on the button inside the lightbox it doesn't work.
At this point I don't know what else to try since all the searches I've done lead to all these.

Here is my code:

```
 <a class="cta" href="http://nextsite.com" id="lightboxCTA">Accept &amp; Install</a>
$('#lightboxCTA').on('click', function(){

                 window.location = "http://google.com";
                 //console.log('Test'); It gets to here but doesn't redirect
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

```
$(document).on('click', '#lightboxCTA', function() {

    if (window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com")) {
        alert('replace');   
    }
    else if (window.location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com') {
        alert('href');
    }
    else {
        alert('none');
    }
});
```

And check if something works